# What Font Is Used For ASOT 2014 Cover?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

Does anyone know what font this is? Is it custom-made for the music label? There are also posters with the same font, only in a light version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be [Avant Garde Gothic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/avant-garde-gothic/) - the 'R' glyph is the giveaway:

[image]